# Допустимо ли использование переменной в строке sql-запроса для значения `ORDER BY` в контексте безопасности?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Существует задача в sql-запросе использовать переменную для значения `ORDER BY`.

Мне известно, что названия столбцов и название таблицы невозможно *"биндить"*.

Прошу совета, насколько безопасна конструкция, когда в строку запроса вставляется переменная `$sort` с жестко заданными вариантами значений, например:

```
 if ($_POST['sort'] == "DESC") {
    $sort = "`title` DESC" ;
 } else {
    $sort = "`price`" ;
 }

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` 
         WHERE `id` = ? 
         ORDER BY " . $sort . " 
         LIMIT ?,?      
        " ;

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);   
 $stmt->execute(...
```

Более расширенный вопрос: насколько плоха (или допустима) практика, когда в переменную помещается часть запроса, например:

```
if ($_POST['column'] == "1") {
   $var_sql_str = " AND `column` = '' " ;      
} else {
   $var_sql_str = "" ;      
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` 
        WHERE `id` = ? 
        " . $var_sql_str . "
        ORDER BY " . $sort . " 
        LIMIT ?,?      
       " ;    

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);   
$stmt->execute(...
```

Comment: $var_sql_str во втором примере определяется после $sql

Comment: спасибо, исправил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, жесткая фильтрация по безому списку является безопасной и рекомендована к применению как раз для таких случаев.

Сборка запроса из частей, жестко прописанных в коде, также является едним из основных способов строить запросы с заранее неизвестным количеством условий.

Чтобы сделать ответ более полным, при сборке запроса из частей обычно используются переменные. **Разумеется**, эти переменные должны также добавляться через плейсхолдерыю Пример можно посмотреть здесь: [How to create a WHERE clause for PDO dynamically](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where):

```
// always initialize a variable before use!
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

// conditional statements
if (!empty($_GET['name']))
{
    // here we are using LIKE with wildcard search
    // use it ONLY if really need it
    $conditions[] = 'name LIKE ?';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_GET['name']."%";
}

if (!empty($_GET['sex']))
{
    // here we are using equality
    $conditions[] = 'sex = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['sex'];
}

if (!empty($_GET['car']))
{

    // here we are using not equality
    $conditions[] = 'car != ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['car'];
}

// the main query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

// a smart code to add all conditions, if any
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

// the usual prepare/execute/fetch routine
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

В общем, основная идея в том, чтобы собрать все переменные в массив, который затем передать в execute()